# Error Table Creation

Tags: tables, errors

I have code for table creation but it doesn't work:

the code:

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Hourly mean values of WSN Observations in $2007-09-29$. }
    \label{tab: wsnhmn29}
            \centering
                \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \texttt{Date & Time }  &   \texttt{WSN25}    &   \texttt{WSN28}  &   \texttt{WSN29}  &   \texttt{WSN31}  &   \texttt{WSN32}     \\ \hline
9/29/2007 0:00 & -1.86 & -1.87 & -1.25 & -1.49 & -1.61 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 1:00 & -1.63 & -1.59 & -0.39 & -1.46 & -1.64 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 2:00 & -1.81 & -1.61 & -0.50 & -1.83 & -1.76 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 3:00 & -2.02 & -1.61 & -0.65 & -1.69 & -1.84 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 4:00 & -2.04 & -1.84 & -0.75 & -1.82 & -1.89 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 5:00 & -1.81 & -1.62 & -0.45 & -1.67 & -1.83 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 6:00 & -1.72 & -1.82 & -0.89 & -1.70 & -1.85 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 7:00 & -1.89 & -1.93 & -0.81 & -1.83 & -1.79 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 8:00 & -1.42 & -0.97 & -0.57 & -1.23 & -1.36 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 9:00 & -0.18 & 1.52 & 0.86 & 0.56 & -0.44 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 10:00 & 1.33 & 1.81 & 1.42 & 1.73 & 1.05 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 11:00 & 2.25 & 3.02 & 2.95 & 2.87 & 1.91 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 12:00 & 3.43 & 3.83 & 3.54 & 3.61 & 2.77 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 13:00 & 4.43 & 5.03 & 4.13 & 4.68 & 3.30 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 14:00 & 4.85 & 5.48 & 4.66 & 5.45 & 3.90 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 15:00 & 5.14 & 5.69 & 4.86 & 5.40 & 4.04 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 16:00 & 5.83 & 5.88 & 5.15 & 6.02 & 4.57 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 17:00 & 4.32 & 3.91 & 3.88 & 4.16 & 3.54 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 18:00 & 2.08 & 2.17 & 2.41 & 2.14 & 1.47 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 19:00 & 1.29 & 1.29 & 1.89 & 1.49 & 0.85 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 20:00 & 0.90 & 0.96 & 1.48 & 0.89 & 0.46 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 21:00 & 0.18 & 0.20 & 0.70 & 0.13 & 0.25 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 22:00 & 0.19 & 0.14 & 0.74 & 0.32 & 0.40 \\    \hline
9/29/2007 23:00 & 0.26 & 0.34 & 0.73 & 0.39 & 0.40 \\    \hline
                \addlinespace
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\&` to print the symbol `&`. `Date \& Time`.

[image]